# AWS S3 manifest.json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a *simple* question - I'm an AWS noob.

I've **picked up a existing project (from previous developers)** that uses AWS S3 as it's file host and media is contained in folders organized like:

`....../<uuid>/picture.jpg`

`....../<uuid>/video.mp4`

also, there is also a  `....../<uuid>/manifest.json` that just has this value:

```
{
    picture: "picture.jpg",
    video: "video.mp4"
}
```

There is only code to create this manifest file, but never fetched or used anywhere else, so I'm not sure if there's an underlying purpose with AWS to be there.

**Is this file necessary?**

If I continue to process uploads, but exclude this `manifest.json`, will anything break?

I've found this related article to manifest files, however the formatting is different and this project doesn't use quicksight so I'm not sure of its purpose here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html

Comment: It's not required for the functioning of Amazon S3. It's your system, so only you would know how it is being used. If you have a Test system, you can try removing it and see what breaks!

Comment: most likely it is used by something that performs a  COPY operation in your system

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file is mainly used to tell the 'consuming' code/application, which files are to be used and where they are. I guess your system is also doing the same but you don't know it yet.

Also, this is more of a design question then a technical one. So please try to find out where it is being used or as John suggested, try to run you application without it and then probably some errors will pop up or the code won't work as expected.